# Помогите определить характер речевой ошибки: плеоназм или тавтология и исправить предложение

Tags: грамотная-речь, недопустимая-метка, плеоназм, тавтология

Эти слушатели успешно прошли обучение и тестовые испытания в соответствии с программой, разработанной Российским сертификационным комитетом по логистике, отвечающей требованиям Европейской логистической ассоциации и Европейского сертификационного комитета по логистике.

Answer (score 2):

Из-за согласованности падежей в сочетании слов "... логистике, отвечающей..." между ними возникает ложная логическая связь, в то время как "отвечающей" должно относиться к программе. Можно было бы устранить этот эффект заменой запятой на союз "и" (разработанной... и отвечающей...), но этому мешает второе "и". Поэтому лучше закончить на этом предложение (... по логистике.) и начать новое словами: "Эта программа отвечает...".

Answer (score 1):

Эти слушатели успешно прошли обучение и тестовые испытания в соответствии с разрабротанной Российским сертификационным комитетом по логистике программой, отвечающей требованиям Европейской логистической ассоциации и Европейского сертификационного комитета по логистике.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно,"успешно прошли" - плеоназм.Привычный,но от этого не менее очевидный.Для проверки зададим вопрос: а можно пройти не успешно? Это вообще удобный тест на плеоназмы - сомнительное слово мысленно заменяется противоположным по смыслу (или резко отличающимся),и если получается абсурд - значит,перед нами плеоназм.К примеру,"проблема нашла СВОЕ решение"(а могла бы найти чужое?).

Comment: пройти не успешно? Да на троечку... Как здесь, — с пунктуацией.